# extract data from site and put into a file

Tags: php

got this project where the client has lost their database,hence i got to look up into their current(live)site and retrieve information... problem is that there is too much data that i have to copy and insert into the database which is taking a lot of time ...could you suggest some code which could help me ?

Comment: Define "data". Retrieving the full HTML code is going to be easy. Retrieving only relevant parts of it is probably going to be hard.

Comment: If they don't have a database, what's driving their live site?

Comment: David: Probably static files generated from the database.

Comment: Did your client consider buying data recovery?

Answer (score 1):

You can use DOMDocument library for php and write automated scripts to retreive data after identifing where are your informations in the page usin tags.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

The library is very robust and uses xpaths.
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp

Answer (score 0):

If the pages are all very similar in structure, you could try to use regular expressions or a html parser (tidy) to filter out the relevant data.

I did a similar thing for a customer who had 200+ handwritten product pages with images, titles and text. The source seemed to have been copy-pasted from the last page, and had evolved into a few different flavors. it worked great after some tweaking.